# OpenGL Cg Geometry Shader

Tags: opengl, cg

I'm getting a compiler error when trying to initialize a geometry shader using OpenGL.  I'm using VS2013.
Here is how I initialize it on OpenGL

```
myCgContext = cgCreateContext();
cgGLSetDebugMode(CG_FALSE);

cgSetParameterSettingMode(myCgContext, CG_DEFERRED_PARAMETER_SETTING);

CGprofile gpProfile = cgGLGetLatestProfile(CG_GL_GEOMETRY);


if (gpProfile == CG_PROFILE_UNKNOWN) {
    if (cgGLIsProfileSupported(CG_PROFILE_GLSLG))
        gpProfile = CG_PROFILE_GLSLG;
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: geometry profile is not available.\n", gpProfile);
        exit(0);
    }
}


cgGLSetOptimalOptions(gpProfile);
OpenGLRenderer::checkForCgError("selecting geometry profile");

CGprogram prog = cgCreateProgram(myCgContext, 
                                    CG_SOURCE, 
                                    "geometry_particles.cg",
                                    gpProfile, 
                                    "geometry_passthru",
                                    NULL);
OpenGLRenderer::checkForCgError("Geometry program");
```

When I call the function checkForCgError, the compiler throws the following error message:
The compiler returned an error. (1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting "::" at token '.'

My geometry shader is located in the file "geometry_particles.cg" and the code is

```
// Geometry pass-through program for colored triangles
void geometry_passthru(AttribArray<float4> position : POSITION, 
                    AttribArray<float4> color   : COLOR)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        emitVertex(position[i] :POSITION, color[i] : COLOR);
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on why the compiler is throwing that error.  Am I missing a flag when setting up the shader?

Comment: I can't reproduce given error message. Does it persists if you compile it with standalone `cgc`? (`cgc -entry geometry_passthru -profile gp5gp geometry_particles.cg`). Anyway, in geometry program you have to specify input primitive type, e.g. `TRIANGLE void gemetry_passthrough(...`

Comment: @keltar, thanks for the info, i'm not to familiar with using cgc so I followed the instruction on the following site [link](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=How+To+Compile+CG+Files) which just indicates to set up the directory to where the shader file is located.  I run the commands, but did not get anything back.  I dont know if I'm suppose to get a success/error message.  Also, I realized that I forgot to mention that I'm working on Win8.1 if that makes any difference

Comment: If you run it in cmd, it should output compiled shader's code, or report an error. Have you added `TRIANGLE` specifier before function declaration? Does the same error still persists?

Comment: yes, i added triangle before the void keyword and still get the same error in VS2013, after that i launch cgc and follow the instructions on that site, i also moved the shader file to where cgc is located and run the command you provided.  On both cases when running the commands no output message was generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, haven't seen that without closer look at source. You using `cgCreateProgram`, which takes program *source*, not file name. Compiler tried to parse given string as cg source code, which it isn't - and reported an error.

What you wanted to use is `cgCreatePgrogramFromFile`, or load file contents manually. E.g.

```
CGprogram program = cgCreateProgramFromFile(myCgContext,
                                        CG_SOURCE,
                                        "geometry_particles.cg",
                                        gpProfile,
                                        "geometry_passthru",
                                        NULL);
```

About your cgc empty output - I've never used it on windows, so can't say about that. Maybe setting option to output to file (`-o out_file`) would help.

Comment: thanks, i cannot believe i miss that function name, specially because i'm using it on the other shaders